# What is wrong with my countdown timer method?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nstimer, countdown

Trying to make a countdown timer from a given NSTimeInterval, the label doesn't seem to be updating.

```
- (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender{
      timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)timerAction:(NSTimer *)t {

    if(testTask.timeInterval == 0){
        if (self.timer){
            [self timerExpired];
            [self.timer invalidate];
            self.timer = nil;
        }

        else {
            testTask.timeInterval--;
        }
    }

    NSUInteger seconds = (NSUInteger)round(testTask.timeInterval);
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02u:%02u:%02u",
                        seconds / 3600, (seconds / 60) % 60, seconds % 60];
    timerLabel.text = string;
}
```

Comment: testTask is specified by the user, i've been testing it on a task with a time interval of 10 seconds. It shows the 10 seconds, but it doesn't show anything changing.

Comment: and the time interval never actually decrements

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in the timerAction method?  is it actually being called?

Comment: just tried. yup, its getting called

Comment: I would inspect or NSLog the seconds value and string value.  You should also add a breakpoint in your else section to see if the decrement is occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is, you are decrementing the `testTask.timeInterval` inside the `if(testTask.timeInterval == 0)` , this condition never evaluates to true (because you set it to 10). That is why there is no change in the label.

You need to put that else case after the first if statement (Currently you placed it under second if statement).

You need to write your method like:

```
-(void)timerAction:(NSTimer *)t
{
        if(testTask.timeInterval == 0)
        {
            if (self.timer)
            {
                [self timerExpired];
                [self.timer invalidate];
                self.timer = nil;
            } 
       }
       else
       {
            testTask.timeInterval--;
       }
       NSUInteger seconds = (NSUInteger)round(testTask.timeInterval);
       NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02u:%02u:%02u",
                        seconds / 3600, (seconds / 60) % 60, seconds % 60];
       timerLabel.text = string;
}
```

Comment: @user2533646: I think you need to have a cup of coffee :) Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your if statements are nested incorrectly. Move your else statement to the outermost 'if' like so.

```
    if(testTask.timeInterval == 0){
        if (self.timer){
            [self timerExpired];
            [self.timer invalidate];
            self.timer = nil;
        }
    } else {
        testTask.timeInterval--;
    }
```